# To go fade out?

Tags: grammar, verbs, idioms

- Those sweet memories never seem to go fade out.

In trying to find a short synonym for "to become to fade out," I've come up with "to go fade out." Is this idiomatic and grammatically correct? The reasons I happened to think of this are "go get," "go take," "go eat," "go talk," "go disappear," etc.

And those go-verb verbs, can they work as past and perfect tenses? Like "I went eat something," or "He's gone disappear." I've seen a lot of them working as present tenses but neither past nor perfect.

Comment: 'Those go verbs' as you describe them are not part of any formal register, and in my personal opinion are inelegant enough to belong with 'innit', and 'dunnit'. So I certainly wouldn't bother trying to conjugate them. Of course you can say *go and eat*, which in the past would be *we went and ate at the Bengal Clipper*.

Comment: What is “to become to fade out” supposed to mean? That would be step one in determining what the sentence you’re looking for should be. “To go fade out” doesn’t really make sense, especially not in the context you have it here. My guess would be that what you’re looking for is simply _“Those sweet memories never seem to fade”_.

Comment: @WS2 Go and figure, eh? ;-)

Comment: Instead of 'go fade out' you could say 'Those sweet memories never seem to go away.' That would make perfect sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That is probably how I would say it but always with a direct object. *Go and figure it out yourself*

Comment: @WS2 Exactly: with an object. Without it, the idiomatic expression is always _go figure_. The point that I didn't really make is that I don't think _go + [base form]_ is particularly informal. It's limited to cases where _go_ is in the base form, whether infinitive or imperative, and in those cases, I would actually associate _go and [base form]_ **more** with informal registers.

Comment: @AndySemyonov _Go away_ sounds better with bad memories than with sweet memories to me.

Comment: I think it still sounds fine to me with good memories. Eg. 'Ah how wonder was the summer of 1973! Those good memories never seem to go away!' It was a good experience and perhaps speaker's intent is indeed to not let those memories go away! He's nowhere suggesting they should go away. He's probably emphasizing how good they were that he can't seem to get rid of them.

Comment: @WS2- And if you are just describing the act of going with the intention of eating, you can say, "I am going to eat" "I went to go eat" "I will be going to eat"

Comment: @AndySemyonov- If they are that good, then he won't want to get rid of them at all.  Both "go away" and "get rid of" have negative connotations.

Comment: Is "to go fade out" always not idiomatic whatever the case is? I could find some results on searching this--quotations added, "to go fade out"--on Google. I mean, can it be idiomatic in some other context?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  *Go +[base form]* sounds like something made in America to me. Anyone speaking in the Received pronunciation would almost certainly say *go and [base form]*. Or at least that's my impression. No doubt someone will call up one of those Google charts to prove me wrong, but I am highly suspicious of those in any case.

Comment: "go fade out" seems like a conflation of "fade out" and "go out" to me. "The lights go out..." "The radio went dead..." It's easy to see how the question arose. I agree with Janus Bahs Jacquet that using "go away" is going to raise negative connotations. "Those sweet memories never go away... but I wish they would!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct sentence is:

*Those sweet memories **never seem to fade**.*

[EDIT as per comments: fade out --> fade]

> Ships Monthly - Volume 21 - Page 33
>
> 1986  Old Favourites Return Cruise ships, like opera stars, **never
>   seem to fade out** or retire permanently but always manage one last
>   bow.

and indeed I found:

> ... and She Lives Happily Ever After. ™ - Page 13
>
> Shari Ashley - 2011  And while for the life of me, I can never
>   remember where I put my car keys—**these sweet memories never seem to
>   fade**. I pray they never do.

Comment: I'd say ***out*** is optional at best and I'd probably not use it unless I was trying for some sort of metaphor that needed it.

Comment: I agree with @Jim. If I wanted to include a preposition, I would use _away_ here, rather than _out_, but most likely I wouldn't use any preposition.